# REST API authentication with yii2-pluto and react

Tags: yii2, react-big-calendar

I wrote an application which have a backend part in yii2 (basic template). And I use *react big calendar* in one part of this app. The calendar gets its events via REST api call into one controller path of yii2. All works as expected.

Now I want to add an authentication layer, so I used *yii2-pluto*. And there is my problem. I am not sure, how to authenticate the api call. I probably could pass back the auth_token from backend inside headers. But I am not able to exclude the api url from the pluto authentication. Pluto intercepts all url paths and checks whether user is authenticated or not. So now my api url always renders login form and sends it back.

I tried to use behaviors part of the api controller, but it did not work.

Is my approach completely wrong, or I just missed some important part? Thanks.

Comment: You will probably have to turn off pluto's "fence mode" and properly set AccessControl filter using roles at controller level. That way you should still be able manage user/roles through Pluto and you will be able to use for example [`yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-auth-httpbearerauth) filter to authenticate api user. You need to make sure the auth filter you are using is applied before the AccessControl filter.

Comment: @MichalHynčica You are right, I just found that it is "caused" by fence mode. I did not read the documentation carefully and used "fenceMode => true" as a mean to disable "Register" button.  Thank you for your hint!